# Upgrading Theme

Tags: theme, magento2.3, static-content-deploy

Using Magento 2.3 with Porto theme version 3.1.6, trying to upgrade to 3.1.7. After downloading the theme files and uploading them to my server, I run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But got this error:

[image]

When I reload my website, the CSS styling was all messed up so I opened Chrome's console and saw:

[image]

```
Refused to apply style from 'pub/static/version1549487745/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-m.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to apply style from 'pub/static/version1549487745/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-l.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

The **`.htaccess`** files are in the **`pub/static/`** folder and the permissions are properly set, so it can't be that.

Please help. Now, the styling is all messed up on my shop (front-end only).
How can I fix this issue and update my theme?

Comment: have you tried force redeploying? setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error.